# select number of items in drupal views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Is there a way i can have an exposed filter wherein the user can select the number of items displayed by the drupal view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am nearly positive that you can do this with `hook_views_pre_build (&$view)`.  I know for a fact that you can mess with `$view->pager` to update whether to use the pager or not and to alter the number of items per page.

This is a snippet from a custom module I did:

```
if (is_numeric($perpage) && (int) $perpage > 1) {
  $view->pager["items_per_page"] = (int) $perpage;
} else if ($perpage == "all") {
  $view->pager["use_pager"] = false;
  $view->pager["items_per_page"] = 0;
}
```

I suspect you can turn the pager off and also set the items per page to limit the results.

EDIT:

OK, just saw the part about the exposed filter.  The code snippet is actually from a bit of code that simulates an exposed filter for this case.  The page has some links on it to select the number of items per page.  The links refresh the page, and tack on a `perpage=whatever` parameter.  The hook then sanitizes the input, and basically runs the code snippet above.  I have also done something similar using HTML a select, and then wiring up the parameter w/ refresh using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread in the issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/324092), that appears to be a long requested feature. It has apparently been added to the [6.x-3.x-dev branch](http://drupal.org/node/324092#comment-2496462), so it should be available in the [6.x-3.0-alpha3](https://drupal.org/node/765092) release.

Or if you're using Drupal 7, it has been added to the [7.x-3.x-dev branch](http://drupal.org/node/324092#comment-2627098) too, so it should be in the [7.x-3.0-alpha1](https://drupal.org/node/1016580) release.

Comment: can it be added programmatically? I am working on the drupal 6 version which does not have this and cannot upgrade midway

Comment: If you're working on Drupal 6, you could try the 6.x-3.0-alpha3 release (linked above). Otherwise, you could try applying the patch manually: http://drupal.org/node/324092#comment-2452906 But I wouldn't hold my breath on getting it to apply cleanly.